# Can I have a user emailed when Status is changed?

Tags: email, status, notification

In Channel Preferences, there's a field "Enable recipient list below for channel entry notification?" But AFAIK that's for when a new entry is published. How about for when an existing entry's Status is changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at the add on MX Notify Control http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-notify-control which should allow you to do this.

Alternatively, for even more flexibility take a look at Postmaster http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster

Comment: MX Notify Control worked, thanks! One thing to note is when updating a Status to trigger the email, one has to save by "Submit" and not "Save Revision" or the email won't send.

Answer (score 0):

[Audit Pro](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/audit-pro) also does a pretty good job of letting you set granular notifications.